# Fading text in a cell in a table

Tags: javascript, animation

pretty new to this - I am trying to fade a single value in a table and I am coming unstuck. I have a large table and I need to fad two cells of it. to keep it simple here are the two cells:

```
<td style="padding:10px 5px; color:white;">£10</td>
<td style:"padding:10px 5px;" id="fade">£164.67 </td>
```

Any help would be brilliant

Comment: apologises, I didn't realise I miss-tagged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the  tags an id and then fade them in/out using Javascript or CSS. Example using JS.

```
<td id="tdOne" style="padding:10px 5px; color:white;">£10</td>


    $("someButton").click(function(){
      $("#tdOne").fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work - how would you make it so the duration of the fade took say 1 - 2 seconds and was done when the page loaded?

Comment: Great. You do this as follows - 

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("trOne").fadeOut(2000);
});`

Please upvote and mark my answer as correct if this helps.

Comment: Not so much luck that time. Any other thoughts?

Comment: What was the problem? That should have worked. Please upload a JSFiddle recreating your problem and I can help you.

Comment: I have stripped it right back to what i started off with - forget about the counting function - here it is... http://jsfiddle.net/278wcym1/1/

Comment: Working JSFiddle :)
http://jsfiddle.net/278wcym1/10/
I don't think you had appended the $ to the start of your (document).ready function.

Comment: This JSFiddle fades in the <td> element. I forgot it was the tr element you wanted. Heres an update. 
http://jsfiddle.net/278wcym1/10/

Comment: Brilliant! It works now - Thanks for your help. Can't up vote reputations isn't high enough.